# How to configure the Jenkins ShiningPanda plugin Python Installations

Tags: python, plugins, jenkins

The Jenkins ShiningPanda plugin provides a *Managers Jenkins - Configure System* setting for **Python installations...** which includes the ability to *Install automatically*. This should allow me to automatically setup Python on my slaves.

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to use it. When I use the *Add Installer* drop down it gives me the ability to

- Extract *.zip/*.tar.gz
- Run Batch Command
- Run Shell Command

But I can't figure out how people us these options to install Python. Especially as I need to install Python on Windows, Mac, & Linux.

Other Plugins like Ant provide an **Ant installations...** which installs Ant automatically. Is this possible with Python?

Comment: After an experiment, one thing that might work _on Windows alone_ with the ShiningPanda: Run Batch Command `start /wait msiexec /qn /i C:\users\mklooste\Desktop\python-2.7.14.amd64.msi /l*v python27-install-log.txt`. This installs to `c:\Python2.7`, and requires no admin permission, and waits for the installer to complete. (On a server, you'll need to set [DisableMsi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368304.aspx) to 0.) However, I'm not sure how often this batch command is run; so perhaps an `if` needs to be added.  If I get this to work I'll post a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as my experiments for jenkins and python goes, shining panda plug-in doesn't install python in slave machines in fact it uses the existing python library set in the jenkins configuration to run python commands.

In order to install python on slaves, I would recommend to use python virtual environment which comes along with shining panda and allows to run the python commands and then close the virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks Akshaya. This is the answer I wanted. Looks like there is no proper support for automatically installing Python.

Answer (score 2):

*(This is a Windows-only answer.  Perhaps someone can complement this with a Linux/Unix answer, which is probably even simpler.*)

Here is how we're currently doing automatic Python installations on Jenkins, with the [ShiningPanda Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ShiningPanda+Plugin), for Python 2.7 on Windows, installing to c:\Python27:

- Download the Python Windows MSI installer from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/, and put it on some central share.
- If you're running a server-version of Windows, then make sure to set [DisableMsi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368304.aspx) to 0, i.e., find or create registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer and create a value called DisableMsi and set it to zero.
- On Jenkins => Manage Jenkins => Global Tool Configuration, add a 'Python installation', choose 'Install automatically' and set the label to cover all agent systems to which this applies.  Then choose 'Run Batch Command', and as batch command use something like this:

  ```
  if not exist c:\Python27\python.exe (
      start /wait msiexec /qn /i \\some-central-system\some-share\python-2.7.14.amd64.msi /l*v python27-install-log.txt
  )
  ```

  as shown in the following screenshot:
  [image: Global Tool Configuration for auto-installing Python 2.7.14]

(Notes on how this works: [msiexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490936.aspx) is the tool to run an MSI installer where '/i' means "install", and in the case of Python it does not require elevated permissions.  `/l*v` does verbose logging.  `/qn` is to make sure no UI is shown, and cmd.exe's `start /wait` makes sure that `msiexec /i` waits until the installation completes.)

That's it!

All of the above might very well work with other versions of Python as well.